# Ruby on Rails + WebORB + authlogic + Flex

Tags: apache-flex, authlogic, weborb

I'm developing a Rails project that uses authlogic for authentication. And I have a part in that project that is realized with Flex, and I need to know how a user can be authenticated if he or she is logged in or not.

I've set up a webservice called `UserSessionService` and I was trying to get the user who is logged in, but it doesn't work. If I try to get it with `UserSession.find`, I just get a # as the result (and therefore that's always true).

Here's the UserSessionService.rb:

```
require 'weborb/context'
require 'rbconfig'

class UserSessionService
  def login
    UserSession.find
  end
end
```

I tried to extend the `UserSessionService` class from `Authlogic::Session::Base`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it now with an extra HTTPService in Flex that accesses a function in the UserSessions Controller. For more details, look at
http://blog.sketchit.de/2009/12/flex-mit-ruby-on-rails-authlogic-authenitifizieren/ (sorry, only in german)

thx for your help!
tux

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Flex, but it seems you're looking for a remote authenticator. Here are some ideas:

1. Make sure a user can "log in" on the Rails side, and all of that functionality works. You may want to start with http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example, which is a really good starting place.
2. Make a "TestController" with one action: #logged_in, which just prints "yes" or "no" based on whether you're logged in or not. Then go hit that in a browser - http://localhost:3000/test/logged_in, and see what it says. Then you can try the same in your Flex app.

   ```
   class TestController < ApplicationController
     def logged_in
       render :text => current_user ? 'yes' : 'no'
     end
   end
   ```
3. Throw up a debugger in your app where it checks whether they're logged in, and figure out why not. It's usually related to cookies. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html for how to debug in Rails.

Please let me know how it goes!

Comment: thank you for your answer. The particular problem is, that I'm accessing the rails side with WebORB and so I only have the possibility to access the files in app/services/UserService.rb (for example). In the Services that are provided by WebORB the functions of the Rails framework aren't accessible. I can't access the current_user function or any other function that is defined in the helpers. Do you know how I can access that functions or access a controller through WebORB? thx!
tux

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be helpfull as I'm using WebORB for .NET, but in Flex you can setCredentials on a remoteObject. In WebORB.NET you can use an AuthenticationHandler to see who's logged in.